# Wave Function of an electron

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction

> An electron gets emitted from a cathode to a detector at distance $L$. Find the wave function of the electron given its a one dimensional stationary problem.

Because it is a one-dimensional stationary problem the solution is of the form 
$\psi (x)= c_1e^{ikx}+c_2e^{-ikx}$.

I think the boundary conditions are $\psi (x=0 ) = 0$ and $\psi(x=L)=0$
because the electron can't be outside and the function has to be continuous.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Physics SE! Unfortunately, [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions. Can you try making a question about some concepts that you'd need to solve this problem? Also mention any thoughts you currently have about the solution, and your assessment of their usefulness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct . The boundary conditions are valid.